# Philosophical way to look at classical interpretation of probability

Tags: philosophy-of-science, probability

I was thinking about the classical interpretation of probability. They make the assumption that determinism obtains in the natural world.  Hence, probability is epistemic. Can I see that as a form of epistemology. And what kinds of philosophical school of thoughts are in comparison with the way of thinking like they do in the classical interpretation of probability. Empiricism? That is possible. Platonism? I don't think so, the classical interpretation is not precise enough to assign them to platonism. Can somebody explain if other school of thoughts can be assigned to the classical interpretation of probability?

Comment: See [Interpretations of Probability](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/probability-interpret/).

Comment: They don't give any information at which school of thought they assign the classical interpretation to, unfortunately. If you see it, can you please say me where? @MauroALLEGRANZA

Comment: Bertrand Russell, "Human Knowledge". This is from memory, but you may find the book interesting.

Comment: You can see : Donald Gillies, [Philosophical Theories of Probability](https://books.google.it/books?id=8AlaU82kTrkC&printsec=frontcover), Routledge (2000)

Comment: I thought this book was interesting. von Mises https://books.google.com/books/about/Probability_Statistics_and_Truth.html?id=cLGgnYoHdlsC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button maybe you have already read it.  But I don't remember it addressing philosophical problems except by implication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the major philosophical interpretations of probability?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/30856/what-are-the-major-philosophical-interpretations-of-probability)